# Adding fragrance oil to paraffin wax

Tags: solutions

I am trying to make a highly scented jar candle. I'm having trouble wicking the candle when I put in larger amounts of fragrance oil. It seems to be either too small and drowns or is too large and smokes. Is there a way to add more scented oil to the wax blend. Or are there things I can add to my candle to help this.